# DRY solution for a JQuery animated navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and web development in general and I'm now stuck in a problem that I cannot seem to be able to overcome. I'm looking for a DRY solution for my JQuery animated navigation bar. You can get the idea by taking a look at the following non-DRY jfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#box1').on('click', function() {
    $('#box1').css({'height':'100px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $('#box2').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $('#box3').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
});

$('#box2').on('click', function() {
    $('#box1').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $('#box2').css({'height':'100px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $('#box3').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
});

$('#box3').on('click', function() {
    $('#box1').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $('#box2').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $('#box3').css({'height':'100px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
});
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/cm70947/m06799xh/

What I don't understand is that how can I control the div height in a DRY context so that when e.g. #box1 is clicked, it increases in height from 50px to 100px and other divs decrease from 100px to 50px in the same time? I'm looking for similar behavior as with css transitions. I have another example here illustrating how I think the DRY version would look like (hopefully it will give you an idea of what I'm after here):

http://jsfiddle.net/cm70947/q2nxmaps/

The problem with the second example is that when I click e.g. #box2, then the #box1 remains 100px whereas I would like it to decrease in height from 100px to 50px. I have tried some removeClass/addClass solutions as well but no luck so far.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You already have everything you need in place. Just use `this` and `.not(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').on('click', function () {
        $(this).css({'height': '100px', 'transition': 'height 1s'});
        $('.box').not(this).css({'height': '50px', 'transition': 'height 1s'});
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m06799xh/2/)**

Comment: Thank you for the example. I already tried the this vs .not(this) approach but couldn't implement it properly. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .box class to your #box1, #box2 and #box3 elements, and run this code:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    $('.box').css({'height':'50px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
    $(this).css({'height':'100px', 'transition':'height 1s'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do my best not to hard code values into jQuery, so I would write someting similar to [taxicala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28945984/209259) without the hard coded values:

```
<div id="box1" 
     class="js-box" 
     data-transition-default="50px"
     data-transition-click="100px" > ... <div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.js-box').on('click', function() 
{
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.js-box').each(function()
  {
    if ($this == $(this))
    {
      return;  
    }
    var defaultHeight = $(this).data('transition-default');
    $(this).css({'height': defaultHeight , 'transition':'height 1s'});
  });

  var clickHeight = $this.data('transition-click');
  $this.css({'height':clickHeight , 'transition':'height 1s'});
});
```

Now it's not limited to some specific values for height (could be updated for transition as well), so it is more reusable.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll definitely take a closer look at this approach!

Comment: [I've also updated to denote the specificy of the class](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).